# How to show that a=±b(mod m) is reflexive for both a = b(mod m) and a=-b(mod m)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I want to show the reflexivity of $a = ±a(mod\ m)$. I know that $a \equiv a (mod \ m)$ is valid because there must exists a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a-a = km$, but when it comes to $a \equiv -a (mod \ m)$, the same definition gives $a - (-a) = 2a$. How can we say for certain that 2a is divisible by m? How do I go about showing $a = -a (mod \ m)$ also holds?

Comment: What are you assuming about $m$?

Comment: There's no assumption in particular except that it's an integer

Comment: The the statement is false. If, say, $m=3$, then $2\ne-2\pmod m$.

Comment: Does that mean $a = ±a(mod \ m)$ is not reflexive? Or is it still reflexive even if it holds only for $+a$ and not the other? The problem does specify that $a = ±a(mod \ m)$ means $a$ is congruent to either $+a$ or $-a \ mod\ m$

Comment: All that I am saying is that $a\ne-a\pmod m$ in general. Concerning the question about whether or not $a=\pm a\pmod m$ is reflexive, I don't know what that means.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I assume you want to prove that the relation $\{(a,b): a\cong b\pmod m$ or $a\cong -b\pmod m\}$ is reflexive.

Comment: @Berci You're right, I worded it wrongly

Comment: For that relation you don't need $a\cong -a$ as $a\cong a$ already implies $(a,a)$ being in the relation.

Comment: Oh that's it! Tysm @Berci